# Summarize different category rankings

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, computer-science

I determine the rankings of i.e. 1000 participants in multiple categories.
The results are something like that:

Participant/Category/Place (lower is better):
A|1|1.
A|2|1.
A|3|1.
A|4|7.
B|1|2.
B|2|2.
B|3|2.
B|4|4.
[...]

Now I want to summarize the rankings. The standard method would be to sum up all places and divide it by the number of categories:

Participant A: (1+1+1+7) / 4 = 2,5
Participant B: (2+2+2+4) / 4 = 2,5

But I want to prefer participant A, because he's won 3 of 4 categories.

I could define fixed points for all places, i.e:

Place|Points
1|1000
2|500
3|250
4|125
5|62.5
6|31.25
7|15.625
[...]

Participant A: 1000+1000+1000+15.625 = 3015.625
Participant B: 500+500+500+125 = 1625

The problem is now, that I want to give every place some points, so it's still possible to sort low places. And when I continue to divide the available points by 2, the maximum number of decimal places are insufficient (Available points /2^Number of places).

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [harmonic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean)?

```
4 / (1/1 + 1/1 + 1/1 + 1/7) = 1.272727
4 / (1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/4) = 2.285714
```